# How to access a php variable in external php file using JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, php

In www.example1.com/demo.php I have a variable named

> $x=5

I want to display the value of **$x in www.example2.com**

How to do it?

www.example2.com does not have server-side language support. Can I do it with JavaScipt or does it have a another way to accomplish it?

Comment: Just send the param as a query parameter in the URL (`www.example2.com?x=5`) and fetch it in the new site using JS. [Here's a post about that](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/901115/how-can-i-get-query-string-values-in-javascript)

Comment: the short answer is AJAX

Answer (score 1):

javascriptWantValue.js :

```
// show the waiting circle gif animation ;
$("#waitingCircle").css("display", "block");

$.ajax({
    url: "getValueFromPhp.php?"+paramOptional,
    dataType: "text",
    async: true,
    success: makeuseofValueFromPhp
});

function makeuseofValueFromPhp(valueFromPhp, status123, XHR123) {

    console.log("value from php is : " + valueFromPhp);

    // hide the waiting circle ;
    $("#waitingCircle").css("display", "none");

}// end function makeuseofValueFromPhp()
```

getValueFromPhp.php is :

```
<?php
    $x = 5;
    echo $x;
?>
```